# Simple JavaScript code beginner combining indexOf and slice

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying this beginner book on JavaScript about `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` method. It told me to turn a "World War II" into the "Second World War". I am trying to write

> in history textbook World War II is after World War I

but the output is

> in history textbook the Second World War

```js
var text = "in history textbook World War II is after World War I"

var firstChar = text.indexOf("World War II");
if (firstChar !== -1) {
    text = text.slice(0, firstChar) + "the Second World War" + text.slice(firstChar, 12);
}
alert(text);
```

My question is, How do you keep the string after the replacement from disappearing?

Thank you very much for the input.

Comment: Did you mean `text.slice(firstChar + 12)`? Or where does the  `12` come from?

Comment: `12` is the length for "World War II" it was provided by the book

Comment: As it is, it is going to give you an error if firstChar >= 12, because the beginning of your slice lies beyond its end point.

Comment: If you haven't already learned how....learn how to use `console.log(someValue)` to see what that outputs into browser developer tools console (F12). Using alert is not very efficient and doesn't keep track of prior values you might be interested in seeing all in one place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it universally usable, I'd suggest changing your code snippet like this in addition to correcting the error:

```js
var text = "in history textbook World War II is after World War I"

var searchTerm = 'World War II';
var firstChar = text.indexOf(searchTerm);
var cutLength = searchTerm.length;
if (firstChar !== -1) {
  text = text.slice(0, firstChar) + "the Second World War" + text.slice(firstChar + cutLength);
  }
console.log(text);
```

That gets you the length from the actual string (so it enables you to search for arbitrary strings) and also slices correctly after the term that you wanted to replace.

Comment: With `slice` you have a start and an end point of the slice, _taken relative to the string that you are working on_ instead of a pair of start point and length, as would be the case with `substr`. It's a good thing to beware of this pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
text = text.slice(0, firstChar) + "the Second World War" + text.slice(firstChar+12,text.length);
```